# PayTM SDK : Transaction Failed

Tags: ios, swift, paytm

I am integrating **PayTM** in my app which is in **ios (Swift)** and I am facing issue which title is "**Transaction Failed**" and the message is "**MissingKeys**"

[image]

I have used following code

```
    merchant = PGMerchantConfiguration.default()!

    merchant.checksumGenerationURL = "http://getlook.in/cgi-bin/checksum_generate.cgi"
    merchant.checksumValidationURL = "http://getlook.in/cgi-bin/checksum_validate.cgi"

    merchant.clientSSLCertPath = nil
    merchant.clientSSLCertPassword = nil

    merchant.merchantID = "rriver57770575448885"
    merchant.website = "APP_STAGING"
    merchant.industryID = "Retail"
    merchant.channelID = "WAP"
```

---

```
    var orderDict = [String: String]()

    orderDict["MID"] = "rriver57770575448885" // Merchant ID
    orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP" // Channel Id
    orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Retail" // Industry Type

    orderDict["WEBSITE"] = "APP_STAGING"
    orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = "10"; // amount to charge                      // mandatory
    orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)";//change order id every time on new transaction
    orderDict["REQUEST_TYPE"] = "DEFAULT";// remain same
    orderDict["CUST_ID"] = "123456789027"; // change acc. to your database user/customers
    orderDict["MOBILE_NO"] = "8798987874";// optional
    orderDict["EMAIL"] = "test@paytm.com"; //optional

    let pgOrder = PGOrder(params: orderDict)

    let transaction = PGTransactionViewController.init(transactionFor: pgOrder)

    transaction?.serverType = eServerTypeProduction
    transaction?.merchant = merchant
    transaction?.loggingEnabled = true
    transaction?.delegate = self
    self.present(transaction!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

please help!

Comment: if  you have successfully implement Paytm payment pls can you give github link

Comment: @iParesh You are working in which language Swift or objective - c?

Comment: I am working on swift

Comment: @iParesh I wrote a mail to PayTM help desk because i am facing some issue and they replied me that they are not providing support for ios Swift.  we can integrate PayTM only with Objective -C

Comment: you have integrate Paytm through swift or objective- c?

Comment: @iParesh I haven't Integrated it yet. I had tried to Integrate it in swift but i am getting  "Oops. Something went wrong" Error.

Comment: @KhushbuDesai Could you assist me to integrate Paytm in swift if you have done this well.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code you have missed a parameter called chechSumHash. include that too.

```
orderDict["CHECKSUMHASH"] = CheckSum;
```

checkSumHash can be generated in the backend by the help of Paytm checksum generation kit. the checksum is a unique string which will change according to the parameter that we have send for checksum generation Api

Comment: hi, is it working for you? can you please share the sample swift code?
I am getting the same error with order id = null.

Comment: @ MUHAMMED IQBAL PA Please post the code, that you have used